# Checking which class is being clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have an anchor tag with two different classes in each tag

```
<a class="class1 class2">Click me</a>
<a class="class1 class3">Click me</a>
```

I wanna know which if I click  `class1` anchor, does it have `class2` or `class3`

I tried this but it doesn't execute

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.class1').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).has('class2'))
        {
            alert("class2 tag");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("class3 tag");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try $(this).hasClass instead

Comment: Yes, hasClass() is what you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jquery's `hasClass` method, and not `has`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.class1').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('class2')) {
      alert("class2 tag");
    } else {
      alert("class3 tag");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="class1 class2">Click me</a>
<a class="class1 class3">Click me</a>
```

Because you are only searching for a className, `hasClass` is sufficient.

The reason `has` should probably be avoided here is because `has` is meant to reduce a set of matched elements. Here is the method description from the jquery docs:

> **.has()**
>
> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method to check an element has the provided class or use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method to check the element against the provided element, jQuery object or selector.

```
if($(this).hasClass('class2'))
// or
if($(this).is('.class2'))
```